# Python save data in different way

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

In my code I have a variable where I am getting the count like `4, 6, 8`. What I actually want is:

This is when `count = 6`

```
    New
    A
    New
    B
    New
    C
```

If `count` is 4 then :

```
    New
    A
    New
    B
```

and so on for multiple counts. I want to save the value in this order how can I manage this can anyone please help me related this. Because I want data in this way to save.

I tried this and it is working correctly fine but i just want how can i simplify it

```
def add_booking_step(count):
    if count > 0:
        chars = 97
        for j in range(0, count, 1):
            # print(chr(chars))
            if (j % 2) == 0:
                print('Start')
            else:
                print(chr(chars))
                chars = chars + 1
        return chars
             

add_booking_step(8)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: If you want to store the output of your function to a text file you can use `file = open("test_file.txt", "w")` in combination with `file.write("Start")`, `file.write("chr(chars)")` and finally `file.close()`. But if your code works correctly fine but you want to improve it, please post this quesition on CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same result but more simple

```
def add_booking_step(count):
    chars = 97
    for j in range(count):
        if j%2== 0:
            print('Start')
        else:
            print(chr(chars))
            chars +=1
             
add_booking_step(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when `count` is greater than `chars`? You may write `chars = chars + 1` as `chars+=1`. Finally the step value in the for loop isn't doing anything, you can do without it, you'll have needed it only if you wanted to step by a value(integer) greater than 1, so that should comes to: `for j in range(0, count):`